# Is there away of creating an end point for the Model Choices filed in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, rest

Hi I have a model in Django like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = [
        (1, 'Governments'),
        (2, 'Non Governments'),
        (3, 'Private Sector'),
    ]
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY, default=1 )
```

And to avoid having to change both the backend and frontend of the project every time I add a category
I would like to have an endpoint that returns JSON of value and displays only these categories using the Django Rest Framework?

```
result: [
  {
   value:1,
   display:"Goverment"
  },
  {
   value:1,
   display:"Non Gorverment"
  },
  {
   value:1,
   display:"Private Sector"
  }
 ]
```

Here is a serializer that I tried but I noticed Imay not be doing t the right way.

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    label = serializers.CharField(source='get_category_display')
    value = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_value_number')
    def get_value_number(self, obj):
        return obj.category
    class Meta:
        models = myModel
        fields = ('value', 'label')
```

Comment: Why dont you create a Category model ?

Comment: You can make an OPTIONS request on the model resource and it will return all possible choices of the field. The additional benefit is that if you also have translations of those labels, the API will return the translations when you make the request with a language code on the URL.